# Fejer monotone sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems

The sequence of vectors $(x_n)_n$ is bounded and such that 
$$ \left\| x_{n+1} - y\right\|^2 \leq \left\| x_n - y \right\|^2 - \alpha \left\| F_n(x_n) - x_n \right\|$$
for some $0 < a < 1$ and $y\in \text{fix}(F_n)$. $F_n : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ are $1$-Lipschitz continuous.

Define the set $S = \bigcap_{n =0}^{\infty} \text{fix}(F_n) \neq \emptyset$.

Does $\left\| x_n - y\right\|$ decreases monotonically until $x_n \in S$?

--

What I have done:

- Shown that in the simpler case $F_k = F$ the claim is true by summing over the indices in both sides of the inequality.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $y$?